# Reliable way to fully re-calculate a workbook from scratch

Tags: excel, vba

To measure how efficient a workbook is, I usually set the calculation mode to `manual` then use the following VBA macro to fully recalculate a workbook.

```
Sub calc()

Application.CalculateFullRebuild

End Sub
```

Today, I have a very complex workbook with lots of complex formulas, I tried the above macro, but it took 1-2 seconds to finish. It was clearly not a full calculation from scracth.

Does anyone know what may be the reason and what's the reliable way to fully re-calculate a workbook from scratch?

Comment: Are the formulas all worksheet formulas, or dies your workbook also contain formulas calling VBA UDF?

Comment: They are all worksheet formulas; no VBA UDF is involved.

Comment: The docs for `CalculateFullRebuild` claim it's the same as re-entering all the formulas.  Are there some specific formulas which aren't recalculating?

Comment: Is a better measure of efficiency counting the number of functions used and comparing to the minimum number actually necessary? as in are you building "bloatware"?

Comment: @SolarMike I would like Excel to genuinely re-calculate all the formulas without any previous cache.

Comment: Application.CalculateFullRebuild applies to all open books, maybe this time you only had one open...

Comment: When it comes to anything to do with Excel calculations, Charles Williams is your go to person...
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/